# Off Topic Questions which have not yet migrated posted again on the right network page

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

Just a few minutes ago, I noticed [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35785689/2441442). It seem to belong to another network page. Somebody raised a Offtopic Flag with this comment:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on productivity.stackexchange.com

After that, the author of the question [asked the same question](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/15415/is-learning-by-doing-and-watching-tutorials-actually-profitable) on the networkpage where it belongs to.

What would be the appropriate reaction to this? I am sure the new question would be fine, I am more about the original question.

We have now duplicates, where on stackoverflow no answer exist (but still visible in search or google), but no linking to the question of the right network where a potential answer could be exist.

I feel this should be deleted. Should I raise a flag for moderation attention?

Comment: Follow the off-topic close reason regarding stack overflow.

Comment: If it would have happened to me I would have posed the question on this other stackexchange and deleted my own wrongly posed question. But fortunately it's done automatically if closed and downvoted anyway. So making sure it has a negative score is important here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are asking here. It is not possible (barring intervention by a Stack Overflow, Inc. employee) to migrate a question from Stack Overflow to Productivity. As such, what you did (voting to close as off-topic) was precisely the correct action. The question will be simply closed on Stack Overflow (as it is now), and not migrated anywhere.

The fact that the person re-asked on Productivity is not really our problem. If it is a poor question, or isn't acceptable by their community standards, the Productivity community will deal with it, editing or closing as appropriate.

There is otherwise no way for a question on one site to link to a question on another site. Cross-site duplicates are not a thing.

If you think it is bothersome to have the closed question hanging around, then you can flag it and ask for a moderator to delete it. Use the custom option, the one that gives you a textbox to type into. Explain that the question has been closed as off-topic and already re-asked on another site, so you are requesting immediate deletion. Any moderator worth his or her salt *loves* to click the "delete" button, so they will probably oblige. But consider carefully whether it is worth investing any further time and energy. Closed, downvoted, abandoned questions will be automatically deleted after a few days by a script we affectionately call the "[Roomba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roomba)." This one is a perfect candidate.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the automatic deletion. If the closed question would have been hanging around longer it could have diverted search engine traffic away from its version on Productivity (unless Google penalizes closed questions).

Comment: Well, if you know a question was reasked somewhere else, I would always add a pointer for anyone else. Did that just now.